# Android paint clear flags

Tags: android, paint

This code

```
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
```

has the same effect as

```
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
```

Is it possible to clear both flags using just one command?

Comment: `paint.setFlags( paint.getFlags() & ~(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG) );` - Or even just `paint.setFlags(0)`. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Alternatively: `const int oldFlags = paint.getFlags(); paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG); // Use the paint... finally: paint.setFlags( oldFlags );`

Comment: @Hanno Binder I'm trying to optimize my game for speed - only draw using those flags when units are not moving. This should save some processing time.

Comment: Calling `setAntiAlias(false); setFilterBitmap(false);` will not make any measurable difference in comparison to any other approach.